# Creating a global font handler for a Qt widget application

Tags: c++, qt

A widget-based Qt application has to run on a wide variety of platforms, some of which don't include fonts at all. Therefore I created a global font loader utility class, with the justification that the fonts are used in a large number of classes, and it would look bloated to pass around the fonts everywhere using dependency injection in each GUI class which has to display some text (there are many).

header:

```
class Fonts
{
    private:
        Fonts() {}
        static QFont m_myFont;
        static QFont m_someOtherFont;
        // and so on for other fonts...

    public:
        static QFont &myFont() {return m_myFont;}
        static QFont &someOtherFont() {return m_someOtherFont;}
        static bool initialize();
};
```

c++:

```
bool Fonts::initialize()
{
    int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/fonts/myFont.ttf");
    if (id < 0)
        return false;

    QString family = QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).at(0);
    m_myFont = QFont(family);

    // and so on for all the other fonts
    // ...

    return true;
}

QFont Fonts::m_myFont;
QFont Fonts::m_someOtherFont;
```

---

At the very beginning of my application, I just call

```
Fonts::initialize();
```

And whenever I have to use a font, I can just use

```
label->setFont(Fonts::myFont());
```

However, if I need other properties, I have to declare a local `QFont`.

```
QFont font = Fonts::myFont();
font.setPointSize(20); 
label->setFont(font);
```

This works just fine, however, I'm thinking whether this is really the most elegant approach.